# ¿Por qué "pata de banco" es "un absurdo", "un despropósito"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones

El Diccionario de la Lengua recoge [**pata**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S71hGRM) como

> 1. f. Pie y pierna de los animales.
>   2. f. Pie de un mueble.
>   3. f. En las prendas de vestir, cartera, golpe.
>   4. f. coloq. Pierna de una persona.
>   5. m. y f. coloq. Bol., Cuba y Perú. amigo (‖ persona que tiene amistad).

y [**pata de banco**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S71hGRM) como

> 1. f. coloq. Absurdo, despropósito.

Por otro lado, [**banco**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4wkKYpU) es

> 1. m. Asiento, con respaldo o sin él, en que pueden sentarse dos o más personas.
>   2. m. Madero grueso escuadrado que se coloca horizontalmente sobre cuatro pies y sirve de mesa para labores de carpinteros y otros artesanos.

No solo no hay nada en la definición de banco que indique que no tengan "patas", sino que una búsqueda en internet encuentra imágenes de bancos con patas ([**ejemplo 1**](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSImjEUQb4cclwcf3HhqKXMWX4lNTbGq5sJNlXl-LVNdG-4eAcIRw) o [**ejemplo 2**](https://static.westwing.es/i/ES-AN030WW37BLUES-1-catalog.jpg)) y varios fabricantes de patas de banco como [**aquí**](http://tiendadeforja.com/46-decoracion-patas-para-banco-fundicion-hierro) o [**aquí**](http://domingotorres.com/seccion/p/mobiliario-urbano/patas-de-banco), mientras que [**aquí**](http://bricolaje.facilisimo.com/reportajes/carpinteria/construye-un-banco-de-madera_183136.html) se dan instrucciones detalladas para construir un banco de madera con patas.

No parece, por tanto, que sea absurdo que los bancos tengan patas.

¿Por qué es "pata de banco" un "absurdo, despropósito"?

Comment: Parece que la expresión completa es "salida de pata de banco". _Ella dijo algo absurdo_ = _Ella tuvo una salida de pata de banco_. Por acá por Chile no lo usamos y yo nunca lo había escuchado.

Comment: @Rodrigo: parece que hay cierta confusión entre http://dle.rae.es/?id=X3Vgn3X "**salida de pie de banco** = **Reacción extemporánea y disparatada**" y http://dle.rae.es/?id=S71hGRM "**pata de banco** = **Absurdo, despropósito.**", que es lo que plantea Manuel

Comment: No hay apariciones en el CORDE de la expresión, pero sí en el CREA, por lo que debe de ser bastante reciente. En cambio, las salidas "de pie de banco" sí aparecen en el CORDE.

Answer (score 2):

A pesar de que la forma actual de la expresión es "tener salidas de pata de banco", se ve que originalmente era de la siguiente forma:

> **Razón de pié de banco.** Phrase vulgar con que se expressa, que se lo que se dice o se responde es de ningun fundamento, ni substancia.

Esta definición la podemos encontrar en el diccionario de autoridades (tomo A-B de 1726) de la RAE. En 1770 se cambió a:

> Locucion familiar con que se expresa que la razon que se da no satisface ni convence.

El ejemplo que pone es:

> *Y si los pedís razón, cumplen con un pie de banco y con que les costó su dinero.*
>
> - Francisco López de Úbeda, "La pícara Justina", España (1605)

Por la época de este último ejemplo, en 1611 Covarrubias recogía la expresión "razón de pie de banco" significando sencillamente "la necedad". No puede ser más conciso. Sin embargo (y desgraciadamente), ningún diccionario consultado explica el origen de la expresión.

Answer (score 1):

Mi interpretación es que, cuando un banco cojea porque ha perdido una pata, cualquier cosa a mano (una piedra, una madera, un saliente de la pared, una pila de libros, etc.) puede servir para salir del paso, aunque a nadie se le escapa que no es la solución adecuada, ni va a ser (seguramente) duradera, ni es el arreglo que necesita el banco. Es decir, originalmente "salida de pie/pata de banco" signficaría "respuesta improvisada" (y, por tanto, ilógica, poco meditada)  pero con el tiempo devino en "despropósito" (igual que no era el propósito de esa cosa ─ahora pie/pata de banco─ servir de apoyo a un banco) y de ahí a "absurdo".

El significado de la RAE de "salida de pie de banco": «Reacción extemporánea y disparatada» creo que es simplemente una variante de la otra.